# play audio from CouchDB with Python

Tags: python, couchdb

**Task:**

1. connect to CouchDB/my_db_name/doc_id/song_title.mp3
2. Using Python GUI play this file
   Steps Done:
3. with help of CouchDB.view I can:
   song = db.view('GET http://localhost:5984/music_box/62d7197138e555dac43a73048401f4ac/Busta Rhymes - Dangerous.mp3')
   and respond of this is: <class 'couchdb.client.ViewResults'>
4. using PyGame(https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) I am able to play .mp3 from a dir.

**Question:**

how to fetch this mp3 file into a new dir, from where I am able to play it

or maybe do this directly from CouchDB ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I was able to store the result as a .mp3 file using the curl command:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/music_box/doc_id/file_name.mp3>~/Documents/test.mp3
```

and it worked.

[image: from CouchDB fetch audio file to a local directory]